# How to keep foot when doing a benchpress?

Tags: bench-press

Some people keep foot flat on ground when benching, some do with toes on the ground with heels lifted... how do I figure out what's correct for me?

Answer (score 2):

If you are competing, different federations have different rules about this. In that case, consult your federation rule book. If you aren’t competing, it doesn’t really matter: just experiment with different placements and figure out what you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

Some prefer flat feet for stability, while others use toes on the ground for more arch and reduced bar distance.

Answer (score 0):

Some powerlifting federations require feet to be flat on the ground, so if you have plans to compete in any of those federations then the choice is made for you.

Beyond that, it's just what you feel is more comfortable for you. Feet flatter on the ground may provide more leg drive. Some people prefer to have a more dramatic arch, so they move their feet beneath them. If they don't have a lot of ankle mobility then they would put their feet up.